# Get Span text inside td on class attribute click event

Tags: jquery

I have below code,

```
<td class="tdclass">
<span id="hiddenspan"> spantext </span>
</td>
```

jquery code

```
$(".tdclass").click( function (event) {

 var span = $(this).parent.children('span').get(0);
 var spantext = span.innerText;
 alert(spantext);

});
```

I am getting Undefined error. Can you please let me how to get span text on class attribute click event?

Comment: There's something wrong with your `.parent.children('span')`. Try `$(this).find('span').get(0)`. Also switching between vanilla javascript and jQuery seems of no use in your example. You can do `span.text()` and leave the whole `.get(0)` idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(this).parent().children('span')` is targeting elements on the same level as your `td`.

Instead, omit the `.parent()` and use:

```
var span = $(this).children('span');
```

`.parent()` takes you up one level, presumably to a `tr`, and then `children()` looks back down at all the elements directly within the `tr`, which again i presume would be `td` tags.

Also, use `.parent()` instead of `.parent`.